# Twitter: Search my tweets and retrieve user ids, cross reference with my followers?

Tags: xml, twitter

First off, I'm doing a contest where users must tweet a message 'just entered #cool-contest, more info at http://unique/url/239843' and I'm basically doing a search using the api:

http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=%40twitterapi+OR+%40twitter

Sample entry element:

```
  <entry>
    <id>tag:search.twitter.com,2005:5266369259</id>
    <published>2009-10-29T19:03:56Z</published>
    <link type="text/html" href="http://twitter.com/mytweetsnl/statuses/5266369259" rel="alternate"/>
    <title>THE_REAL_SHAQ: Shaq-A-Claus is coming to town! Check out my &#8220;Join Shaq Give Back&#8221; challenge, coming.. http://bit.ly/1OVKHR</title>
    <content type="html">THE_REAL_SHAQ: &lt;b&gt;Shaq-A-Claus&lt;/b&gt; is coming to town! Check out my &#8220;Join Shaq Give Back&#8221; challenge, coming.. &lt;a href=&quot;http://bit.ly/1OVKHR&quot;&gt;http://bit.ly/1OVKHR&lt;/a&gt;</content>
    <updated>2009-10-29T19:03:56Z</updated>
    <link type="image/png" href="http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/298078521/twitter_normal.gif" rel="image"/>
    <twitter:geo>
    </twitter:geo>
    <twitter:source>&lt;a href=&quot;http://twitterfeed.com&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;twitterfeed&lt;/a&gt;</twitter:source>
    <twitter:lang>en</twitter:lang>
    <author>
      <name>mytweetsnl (MyTweets.nl)</name>
      <uri>http://twitter.com/mytweetsnl</uri>
    </author>
  </entry>
```

I'm basically trying to search all retweets of the initial user ( me ) and tracking the string '#cool-contest' and 'http://unique/url/239843' from the content element, then inserting the entries into a local database, but before I actually insert the entry I also need to determine whether said user is a follower or not, and this is why I need the user id to cross reference with followers:

http://twitter.com/followers/ids.xml?screen_name=101010

Is there an extra parameter I'm missing so I can actually see the user ID? If not would the only way be to parse the twitter URI, so grab the username after 'twitter.com/user' from the `author` element and feed it as a name parameter?

http://twitter.com/followers/ids.xml?screen_name=mytweetsnl

I'm just a little hesistant because I'm not sure if the screen name is reliable since it may be updated in the future.

My initial questions about this project ( if you want more info ): [Tweet Contest logic ( Twitter )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648161/tweet-contest-logic-twitter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the json format of the [Twitter search API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-Search-API-Method%3A-search).

**Curently, the user_ids from the search API are not the same as the Twitter user IDs used everywhere else.**  This is a common problem.

> The user ids in the Search API are different from those in the REST API ([about the two APIs](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/API-Overview)). This defect is being tracked by [Issue 214](http://code.google.com/p/twitter-api/issues/detail?id=214). This means that the to_user_id and from_user_id field vary from the actualy user id on Twitter.com. Applications will have to perform a screen name-based lookup with the [users/show](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-users%C2%A0show) method to get the correct user id if necessary.

Comment: Since I have to rely on the screen name anyway, do you think I should just not bother with the user id and instead rely solely on the screen name?

Comment: Actually I might still have to rely on the user id because the page with followers only returns user ids... ack.

Comment: Yeah, whether you need to look up the true user ID is dependent on what you want to do.  This is truly a big flaw in the search API and one that's been outstanding for too long.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the search API and parse the json you can get the from_user_id property and therefore their user id

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=google

Comment: Ahh, I should have checked the json version of that, thank you.